# java having same class name and package name

Tags: java

In java, can we have a class name with the same name as package name?
For example,

```
 package abc;
 class abc{
 }
```

Note: I know class name should start with a capital letter so please ignore it for this case.

Comment: try it! it will take much less time than writing a question here. am i wrong?

Comment: yeah I tried it but this question may help someone someday

Comment: Yes, it will work.  You can have a class named abc.abc.abc.abc if you want.  What gets confusing is when you have a class named abc.abc.abc.abc and another one named abc.abc.abc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely fine. Your class `abc` will be referred as `abc.abc` in terms of qualified path.